# How do I deal with the quantity column of a junction table using sql to entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables. Blog and Tag have a many to many relationship. BlogTag is a junction table with a quantity column.

```
**Blog**
BlogID
Title

**Tag**
TagID
Name

**BlogTag**
BlogID
TagID
Quantity
```

I'm not sure how I handle the quantity column. I'd like it to store how many Blogs have a certain Tag Name

How do I deal with the quantity column when adding a new blog that has tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd need to calculate the quantity:

```
var q = (from b in Context.Blogs
         where b.BlogTags.Any(t => t.Tag.TagId == someId)
         select b).Count();
```

So you:

```
1. Add the blog
2. SaveChanges
3. For each tag on the new blog:
    1. Calculate the quantity, as above.
    2. Update the BlogTag.Quantity.
4. SaveChanges
```